# MvxImagePickerTask no funciona en ios

Tags: ios, xamarin

Tengo este codigo para capturar una imagen en xamarin ios, pero no hace nada.

```
    private void DoTakePicture()
    {
        try
        {
            _pictureChooserTask.TakePicture(400, 95, OnPicture, () => { });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _dialogService.ShowToast(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

la salida es MvxImagePickerTask called when task already active
tengo los permisos añadidos.
alguien puede saber que pasa?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esta solución en [StackOverflow (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22431412/6203030)

Al parecer tienes que sobreescribir el PresentModalViewController en tu presentador customizado:

```
    public override bool PresentModalViewController(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
{
    var currentViewController = _flyOutNavigationController.ViewControllers[_flyOutNavigationController.SelectedIndex] as UINavigationController;
    currentViewController.PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);
    return true;
}
```